# Why you can answer a question that is closed?

Tags: support, questions

I come to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31224477/3653989) and when I send my answer I see that the question is closed 4 minutes ago. I think that this is possible because I was writing in the moment at a user has marked the question as duplicate. But I think that if a question is closed, I shouldn't post a answer.

Comment: why vote down? Can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have answered the question correctly (within the given posting grace period), and it's been accepted it seems.

Though there is a duplicate, that was answering the question earlier (or even later and better), and a user (with the appropriate powers) marked it as such.

That doesn't make your answer bad, or less useful for future research. You shouldn't worry about such situation.